# Excepción en C#. System.AccessViolationException: intento leer o escribir en la memoria protegida

Tags: c#, .net, visual-foxpro, foxpro

Estuve realizando una aplicación en consola en **.NET** con **objetos COM** de **VisualFoxPro**.

Dicha aplicación la corrimos en PC de **64 bits** y todo funcionó perfecto hasta que lo probamos en dos servidores, uno de **64 bits** y otro de **32 bits** hasta que arrojó el siguiente error:

> **System.AccessViolationException:** intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida

cuando intento llamar a un método particular de ese componente.

Dicha aplicación está compilada en **32 bits**.

Acá les dejo el código que arroja el error:

```
public static bool EjecutaGeneraOt(Test test, DataTable dtInput, ref string exceptio)
{
    bool vf = false;
    string resultado = "Se generó la orden: ";
    string error = "Falló la Generación de OT: ";
    try
    {
        string codArticu = dtInput.Rows[0]["cod_articu"].ToString();
        int nroTal = Convert.ToInt32(dtInput.Rows[0]["n_tal_ref"]);
        var cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(dtInput.Rows[0]["cantidad"]);
        if (ObjetoGeneradorDeOt.GeneraConArt(ObjetoUlLogon, codArticu, ref exceptio, cantidad, true, DateTime.Now, "desde Wall-E", DateTime.Now, "", 0, "", 0, "", "", "", "", "", ""))
        {
            test.Resultado = resultado + ObjetoGeneradorDeOt.UltimoNumeroOT;
            _log.Info(resultado + ObjetoGeneradorDeOt.UltimoNumeroOT);
            vf = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _log.Error(error + exceptio);
            test.Resultado = error + exceptio;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.Error(error + e.Message, e);
        test.Resultado = error + e.Message;
        vf = false;
    }
    test.ConError = !vf;
    return vf;
}
```

El método se llama **GeneraConArtTal**.

Este es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Tienen alguna idea para resolver este error?

Saludos.

Comment: ¿El origen del error está en el código que colocaste en tu pregunta o en el método `GeneraConArtTal`? Mira el `StackTrace` para saber la línea exacta donde se dispara el error.

Comment: El error me lo tira el método **GeneraConArtTal** . Sí, me tira es ese método. Lo que tengo pensado es que el error se da por el objeto COM de VFP.

Comment: *Dicha aplicación está compilada en 32 bits.* : ¿estás seguro?  Usualmente, por allí va el problema...

Comment: Si si, toda la aplicación esta compilada en 32 bits. Porque los objetos COM están en 32 bits, de lo contrario no podría compilar.

Comment: @NahuelPicca podráis poner el código de ObjetoGeneradorDeOt.GeneraConArtTal

Comment: Para tener una mejor idea, debes pegar aquí el StackTrace completo de la excepción.

Comment: Cuando te salta ese mensaje, te lo tira en laguna excepción que controlas? En que catch te está mostrando este mensaje???

Comment: No le da bola al catch, me tira el error y le se cierra la aplicación.

Comment: @Pikoh ya se cual es la línea que genera el error y es esa.

Comment: Qué línea? no consigo ver cual es exactamente.  Puedes marcarla de alguna manera en tu código o especificarla claramente en tu pregunta?

Comment: Por otro lado...el código que nos pones,es todo el código de un método? te importaría añadir un poco mas de código para que veamos ese método completo?

Comment: @Pikoh la linea seria: `if (ObjetoGeneradorDeOt.GeneraConArt(ObjetoUlLogon, codArticu, ref exceptio, cantidad, true, DateTime.Now, "desde Wall-E", DateTime.Now, "", 0, "", 0, "", "", "", "", "", ""))`. Hay agregé el método completo.

Comment: Este error es muy común cuando una variable declarada para 64bit se intenta escribir sobre una preparada para 32bit, ya sea cuando se pasa como parámetros o se intenta asignar directamente. Por el error veo que estas usando dos proyectos .NET (CzTestingConsola y Negocio), asegura que todos los proyectos vinculados a esta prueba estén compilando a 32bit, ninguno debe estar con "Any CPU".

Comment: Al proyecto está compilado en 32bits y lo corrí en 3 computadoras de 64bits y anduvieron perfecto.  Cuando lo ejecutamos en un servidor de 32bits y otro de 64bits, explotó. @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cuando escribes "lo ejecutamos en un servidor de 32bits y otro de 64bits". Esto significa que la aplicación establece una comunicación entre dos servidores uno de 32 y otro de 64?

Comment: Lo que quise decir es que llevamos la aplicación a los servidores y los ejecutamos ahí. No se si me entiendes. @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez

Comment: Podrías subir la captura de pantalla de el registro de windows porque al parecer esta en uso un componente que usa para tu acción de IO.

Comment: Me fije las rutas de los componentes en el registro de windows y están correctos. @JoseAntonioDominguezGarcia